# Wordpress permalink filter

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

i want to make the urls relative by using the the_permalink filter but its not working.And I am confused hwo to fix that issue,

```
function root_relative_permalinks($input_urls) {
    return $input_urls.'?urlsnowworking=23';
}
add_filter('the_permalink','root_relative_permalinks', 10000,1);
```

I have used the above code to test but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you put simple function separately in your script, where you want to use it like:

```
function root_relative_permalinks($input_urls) {
    return $input_urls.'?urlsnowworking=23';
}
```

and noe use it like this:

```
$url = the_permalink();

$input_urls = root_relative_permalinks($url);
```

Thanks.